# MFC VS 2008 TabControl - Can't add variable

Tags: visual-studio-2008, mfc

I thought I had this whole MFC thing down.  I was completely wrong.

I started a VS 2008 project, MFC Application, Dialog Based, Shared DLL.  I've made all the dialogs I want to add to the tabbed control and I'm at the step where (as far as I can tell) I add a variable to the tab control to do things with it.  But "Add Variable" is greyed out and I cannot select it.

Basically I'm at the second step of [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yft127ws%28v=VS.90%29.aspx),

Any idea why I can't add a variable to the tab control?

Thank you!

Edit: I have just noticed that if I added a tab control in the default dialog I CAN add a variable.  The dialog I'm trying to put this tab control into is NOT the main dialog.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay - it's simple.  All the examples I were looking at were using the default dialog with the tab control.  To make it possible to add a variable to the tab control of the dialog I needed to first add a class to the dialog (base class: CDialog).

Haven't actually got the tabs working yet, but I'll do that tomorrow, for now I can add variables to the tab control.

tl;dr - Add class - base class: CDialog - to the dialog.  Then you can add variables to tab control